# Video Resize Issue via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a video at [www.remooble.com](http://www.remooble.com) with a video that *sometimes* resizes properly. Here is when/where it doesn't (mostly).

1. In Internet Explorer or Safari (JavaScript just doesn't do what it should be)
2. A users first session (before Cached content)
3. On hard refresh

Here's the JavaScript we're running. As mentioned, it doesn't even function on IE (no resizing in the CSS editor).

Any help here is appreciated! Let me know if I'm missing anything.

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
var $win = $(window);
var $doc = $(document);
var homeVideoIframe = $('#home-video');

function sliderInit( $slider, params ) {
    if ( $slider.length ) {
        $slider.lightSlider( params );
    }
}

function initQuotesSlider() {
    let height = 0;

    $('#homepageSlider > li').each((e, i) => {
        height = $(i).height();
    });
}

function adjustHomeVideoSize() {
    var width = homeVideoIframe.width();
    var height = width / 1.78;
    homeVideoIframe.height(height);
};

$doc.on( 'ready', function () {
    adjustHomeVideoSize();
});

$win.on('resize', function () {
    adjustHomeVideoSize();
});


$win.on( 'scroll, resize', function() {
    $( 'body' ).addClass( 'loaded' );
    initQuotesSlider();

    var testimonialSliderParam = {
        addClass: "quotes-slider",
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 70,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        vertical: false,
        autoWidth: true,
        pager: false,
        item: 4,
        onSliderLoad: function() {
            $('#homepageSlider').removeClass('cS-hidden');
        }
    };

    var $homepageTetimonialsSlider = $('#homepageSlider');

    if ( $win.width() > 1200 ) {
        testimonialSliderParam.items = 1;
    }

    sliderInit( $homepageTetimonialsSlider, testimonialSliderParam );
});

$win.on( 'load', function() {
    $( 'body' ).addClass( 'loaded' );

    initQuotesSlider();

    var productSliderParam = {
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 0,
        item:1,
        addClass: "products-slider"
    }
    var $productSlider = $("#productsSlider");

    sliderInit( $productSlider, productSliderParam );

    $('#productsNext').click(() => {
        $productSlider.goToNextSlide();
    });

    $('#productsPrev').click(() => {
        $productSlider.goToPrevSlide();
    });

    var testimonialSliderParam = {
        addClass: "quotes-slider",
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 70,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        vertical: false,
        autoWidth: true,
        pager: false,
        item: 4,
        onSliderLoad: function() {
            $('#homepageSlider').removeClass('cS-hidden');
        }
    };

    var $homepageTetimonialsSlider = $('#homepageSlider');

    if ( $win.width() > 1200 ) {
        testimonialSliderParam.items = 1;
    }

    sliderInit( $homepageTetimonialsSlider, testimonialSliderParam );

} );

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: For your own debugging and for better get help, you should try to reduce your code to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem. It's the MCVE explained on the help center: [mcve]. And here a nice discussion about it: [What does MCVE mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366988/1287812)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer I found that seems to do the trick. We're using CSS in conjunction as a fallback which is working brilliantly.

```
// Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//player.vimeo.com'], 
iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']"),


// The element that is fluid width
$fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

$(this)
.data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

// and remove the hard coded width/height
.removeAttr('height')
.removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

// Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
$allVideos.each(function() {

var $el = $(this);
$el
  .width(newWidth)
  .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

});

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

Here's the CSS solution:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```